# Getting the directory of a newly created windows user

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows batch file where I create a user as Administrator called Trainee. Then I want to copy some files into the Desktop folder for the Trainee user.

I need to be able to get the Windows desktop folder of this newly created user and copy some files into it. How do I do this?  The %USERPROFILE% only tells me the Administrator user's folder.

```
REM Create the new user
NET user Trainee <password> /ADD
```

Then I copy some files into what I think should be the newly created user, but it keeps changing like adding .000 to trainee or the machine name.

I've tried setting the HOMEDIR and the PROFILEPATH like so

```
NET user Trainee <password> /ADD /HOMEDIR:<some_path> /PROFILEPATH:<some_path>
```

but all this does is sets the path in a DOS prompt for the Trainee user, it doesn't set the Windows path.

... How do I get the Windows home dir for the newly created Trainee user?

I can't use runas as this needs to be completely automatic, not prompting for a password.

Comment: Not sure why this question got a downvote.  If it's so trivial it might be easier to answer it than to just downvote it: however I don't think it is trivial.

Comment: It isn't trivial; it's impossible.  The directory doesn't even exist until the user logs in for the first time.  (Well, not impossible I suppose; you can call `CreateUserProfile`, but not from a batch file.)

Comment: Thanks Harry, that makes sense. I will have to try a different approach, e.g. maybe run a batch file after the new user logs in or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this can't be done, at least with a batch file. The problem is that the user profile is not yet created, so what I will have to do is set up some sort of a batch script to run after the Trainee user logs and do this setup.  Thanks everyone.

I also think the creation of new profiles is due to me copying in files BEFORE anyone has logged in.

Comment: Look here in case you find it helpful... https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/247395-create-a-user-profile-without-logon not sure if there is a workaround for creating the user profile before actually logging onto the machine or not, but may be worth the research and testing for you though. I assume you're not using Roaming Profiles in a domain environment but this posts talks some about that as well with references for further detail. In any case, this was the first google result that came up with that sort of search so wanted to share just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Despite this question being better suited to Super User, your commands don't appear to be creating an administrator account for `Trainee`.

To do that you'd need to use, *as an administrator*:

```
net user /add Trainee Pa55_W0rd
net localgroup administrators Trainee /add
```

Also I'd guess that the new user would need to log in such that their directory structure and account setup is carried out. Until then there is nowhere to copy anything to.

Comment: Hi,  I don't need an administrator account, what I meant was that I was logged in as administrator when I created the Trainee account. That part is OK.

Comment: Run your commands then log the person in, let the account setup log out then copy your stuff over.